# Postgres - returning custom values ie. "true" rather than "t"

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering if there is a way to show custom "values" in the output of a query purely for readability, similar to the `AS` statement for renaming column labels.

Seems unlikely but would be useful for cutting down a number of custom post-query formatting steps.

ie.

```
| type (varchar) | status (boolean) |
| A              | t                |
| B              | f                |
```

as

```
| type  | status |
| A     | true   |
| B     | false  |
```

or

```
| type  | status     |
| A     | collecting |
| B     | disabled   |
```

I am aware I could change the database to contain these values, but this is not possible in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` clause to custom the output :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN status THEN 'true' 
            WHEN NOT status THEN 'false' 
            ELSE 'uknknown' 
       END AS status 
FROM mytable;
```

If you want to change the default output of PostgreSQL in order to output 'true' instead of 't', I'm pretty sure it is not possible.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.